# How to Create alias for a field which is same as the other field name?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I dont know how to make the question.
Here is the case :

Table `category` :

```
id_category
id_main_category
title_category
```

The content's are :

- `id_category :1` | `id_main_category :0` | `title_category : Man`
- `id_category :2` | `id_main_category :0` | `title_category : Woman`
- `id_category :3` | `id_main_category :1` | `title_category : Wallet`
- `id_category :4` | `id_main_category :1` | `title_category : Shoe`
- `id_category :5` | `id_main_category :2` | `title_category : Dress`

> id_main_category = id_category

each field with id_main_category = 0 is a MainCategory, the other is a subCategory of other field with id_category referenced in its id_main_category.

so, Man (id_category 1) is a MainCategory and it has 2 subCategory :

- Wallet (id_category 3)
- Shoe (id_category 4)

I want to select * from category  but also the title of maincategory and print it as :

> - Man
> - Woman
> - Wallet (Man)
> - Shoe (Man)
> - Dress (Woman)

The question is : How to select and create the alias for the title_category of mainCategory, like :
`SELECT *, title_category as title_main_category FROM category WHERE id_main_category = id_category.`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) for this, as you are actually combining different rows into one. This should do the trick

```
SELECT * FROM `category` AS `a`
LEFT JOIN `category` AS `b`
ON `a`.`id_main_category` = `b`.`id_category`
```

Note: you should set `id_main_category` to `NULL` if it is a 'root' category. `0` is a valid ID, so you should not want to distinguish between a root / child based on this arbitrary value. You might have to change your column to allow null values though.

Comment: I inserted another field with id_category = 0, and named it as Main Category.

Comment: Ah. If you are actually using `Main Category` as a category like all others, that's totally fine. But if you've inserted that only to be able to select 'root' categories, that's bad practice and could cause you problems later on.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the exact result you desire.

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.title_category,'(',IFNULL(b.title_category,''),')') 
FROM category a LEFT JOIN category b ON a.id_main_category = b.id_category ;
```

Hope this helped. I have used self join , b category acts like a parent category table here.

Answer (score 0):

As @giorgio said.

```
SELECT *, a.`title_category` AS 'title_main_category' FROM 
`category` AS `a`
LEFT JOIN `category` AS `b` 
ON `b`.`id_main_category` = `a`.`id_category`
```

Thank you